# How do raising skills work in The One Ring?

Tags: skills, character-advancement, the-one-ring

When the adventuring phase ends, PCs can use their advancement points to raise common skills and experience to raise other stats. I hav several doubts about that:

- Is advancement points the only way to raise common skills, or experience can also be used? The advancement points seems to be very few to raise even a single skill, and also there's at least one point where you can use XP to raise common skills: character generation. If XP can be used, how does it combine to AP?
- Must AP be used on the same skill category they were earned or are they just pooled together and used en whatever skill you want?
- How does the system has worked to you?

I know this is explained in the core books, but it seems I fail to understand the rules.

Comment: I apologize in advance if I have messed the game terms. My books are not in english, so I am reversing the translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are totally separated. You spend your advancement points on common skills. You spend experience on combat skills and Valor/Wisdom levels. And they reinforce thusly what you've been doing with your time.

> **SPENDING EXPERIENCE POINTS**
>   Heroes may spend their accumulated Experience points
>   to gain a new rank in either Wisdom or Valour, and to
>   enhance their proficiency in their Weapon skills.
> *(TOR AB p. 170)*

Note that it does not list common skills there. Thus it's not allowed.

> **SPENDING ADVANCEMENT POINTS**
>   Players spend Advancement points to raise their Common
>   skill ranks, using the costs in the table below.Players
>   are not obliged to spend all their Advancement points,
>   but may save them to acquire more expensive upgrades
>   during a later Fellowship phase. Players can also buy
>   multiple ranks into the same Common skill, as long as
>   they pay the cost of every new level individually. Any
>   remaining Advancement points are kept track of using
>   the appropriate space on the back of the character sheet.
> *(TOR AB p. 171)*

AP are pooled - at the fellowship phase, all your marks are tallied, and then you add that total to your available AP. Note that there are only 3 AP per category, and unspent go in the single box on the back of the sheet... and the lowest cost upgrade is 4, so it's impossible to use a single category's AP total to raise a common skill.

Yes, the system worked quite well for me - the separation of AP and EP forced players to use their common skills in order to raise them. Combat is easy - XP are earned pretty steadily. The gaining of abilities and magic item by Virtue and Wisdom ranks worked particularly well.

Comment: How many AP does a player usually gain after a typical adventure?

Comment: It varies, but the highest I saw in a 5 month campaign was about 12 in a session. Needing those exceptional successes (2+ 6's on the d6's) means you can't get the third point per category very often.